# How inheritance will work with different class objects

Tags: c#, oop

Here is an Inheritance question.  I was trying to understand TAG1 to TAG3 Process. what exactly going happen and hold which class reference. Looking forward to your suggestion.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    B b = new B(); **// What Happens here  TAG1**
    A a = b;       **//What Happens here TAG2**
    B x = new A() as B; **//what happens here TAG3**
    a.F();   
    a.G();
    a.H();
    a.Z();

    b.F();
    b.G();
    b.H();
    b.Z();

    x.F();
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public class A
{
    public void F() { Console.WriteLine("A.F"); }
    public virtual void G() { Console.WriteLine("A.G"); }
    public virtual void H() { Console.WriteLine("A.H"); }
    public void Z() { Console.WriteLine("A.Z"); }
}

public class B : A
{
    new public void F() { Console.WriteLine("B.F"); }
    public override void G() { Console.WriteLine("B.G"); }
    new public void H() { Console.WriteLine("B.H"); }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
B b = new B(); **// What Happens here  TAG1**
```

An instance of B is created here, and `b` holds a reference to it.

```
A a = b;       **//What Happens here TAG2**
```

`a` is assigned that `b` instance, which means you can access the `A` part of the previously crated `B` object.

```
B x = new A() as B; **//what happens here TAG3**
```

You create an `A` object and cast it to `B`, but the cast is gonna fail and return `null`. Therefore `x` will not reference the instance of an object.

Comment: Could you please give more description on Tag2 and Tag3. Thanks.

Comment: for TAG3, it is almost equivalent to B x = (B)new A();

But when conversion failed, "as" keyword will return null (while conversion throws exception).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cscsdfbt.aspx